# How to exclude NaNs from ranking a vector

Tags: matlab, sorting, nan

We're working on a MATLAB code to rank stocks. We do not have a full dataset and therefore have to cope with some NaNs. However, in the code we use for sorting, the NaNs are ranked the highest. Our intention is to exclude the NaNs from the ranking. How to do this?

Please consider an example with `Y` and `stockkid` below

```
Y = [1.2 1.3 NaN 0.9 0.95 NaN 0.8 0.7];
stockid = [801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808];
[totalmonths,totalstocks] = size(Y);
nbrstocks = totalstocks - sum(isnan(Y));
[B,I] = sort(Y,'descend');
ncandidates = 4;
idwinner(1:ncandidates) = stockid(I(1:ncandidates));
```

Running the program results in:

```
Y =

    1.2000    1.3000       NaN    0.9000    0.9500       NaN    0.8000    0.7000
idwinner =

   803   806   802   801
```

So, 803 corresponds to NaN, 806 to NaN, 802 to 1.3 etc.

The result we're aiming for should be like this:

```
Y =

    1.2000    1.3000       NaN    0.9000    0.9500       NaN    0.8000    0.7000
idwinner =

   802   801   805   804
```

So, how can we exclude the NaNs from the ranking?

Comment: `stockid(I(sum(isnan(Y))+1:sum(isnan(Y))+ncandidates))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your `sort` statement, add the line: `I = I(~isnan(B));`, which will remove the indices associated with `NaN`s before you select them from `stockids`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Y(isnan(Y)) = -inf;
```

before calling `sort`. That will change `NaN` values into `-inf`, and thus those values will be the lowest.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to change any value in `Y`, you can use an intermediate index as follows:

```
Y = [1.2 1.3 NaN 0.9 0.95 NaN 0.8 0.7];
stockid = [801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808];

ind = find(~isnan(Y)); %/ intermediate index that tells which elements are numbers
[B,I] = sort(Y(ind),'descend');
ncandidates = 4;
idwinner(1:ncandidates) = stockid(ind(I(1:ncandidates))); %// apply intermediate index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I = I(~isnan(B));
```

Works best since we then do not overwrite the NaNs as is the case with using

```
 Y(isnan(Y)) = -inf;
```

Since we later on also have to determine the loser portfolios from the stocks with the lowest returs. This does not work well with the last code because all the NaNs have the lowest returns instead of the stocks with actual data.